# How to update all collection with firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections. One collection "User", who contains the user info (username...) And one collection "Post" who contains all posts of my flutter application. A post document contains a "Text Post" and the "Username" of the writter. I add an option in my application to allow the user to change his nickname every 6 months. But I must change the username in the "User" collection and in all posts it creates in the "Post" collection. What is the best practice ?

1. The user make a query for update username in "User" collection, i intercept the "OnUpdate" in cloud function and i update all post in server side.
2. The user make a query for update username in "User" collection, and update all "Post" collection in client side.

I guess if i do a geDocuments () there is a limit, so I should do it in multiple times if I have too many "Post" Documents, am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no singular best practice here. Both approaches you describe are valid, and neither is pertinently better than the other.

A few things to keep in mind in either scenario:

- You may not be able to handle all updates in a single batched write (since that can handle at most 500 documents at once), so I'd recommend not wasting energy on that.
- In some scenario's it is also acceptable (and sometimes even required) to **not** update the existing documents, so I recommend always considering that too.